# Azure Export creation failed. SAS token access to user storage is not supported

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azureportal, sas-token, azure-billing

I am trying to create Azure Billing Export via Portal Azure with the use of SAS token. I want to export costs from tenant A to storage container in tenant B.
I have generated SAS token in storage account with help of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/export-cost-data-storage-account-sas-key) tutorial, with only change of expire date extension. In storage account there is enabled "Allow storage account key access" configuration.
I am able to connect to storage account via Storage Explorer with use of generated SAS token, but when I try to create export there is error:

> Export creation failed.SAS token access to user storage is not supported.

I can't find anything about this error in MS Azure documentation and also anywhere in the web.
I generated token by Azure CLI, storage account Shared access signature, container Shared access signature and Storage Explorer.
I have not generated User Delegation SAS, because I need long term access.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by lack of needed permissions to perform that action. I don't know which role gives permissions to do that, Global Admin helped a lot.

Comment: Where did you give global admin permission to ? is it the storage account or billing scope?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure, because it was given by our company administrator. I think it could be given to whole billing scope.